# How do I setup Jackrabbit Repository.xml for 2 Nodes with Shared NFS Mount?

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get my repository.xml correct for a 2 node configuration using a shared NFS mount. Should I be using a DB persistence manager for both the PersistenceManager and Journal?

I find the Apache Jackrabbit Wiki obtuse and haven't been able to avoid this error:

*20:47:34.804 [pool-1-thread-3] WARN  o.a.j.core.util.RepositoryLock - Existing lock file /export/attachments/.lock detected. Repository was not shut down properly.*

If you have an example repository.xml, please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's true that all Jackrabbit cluster nodes need access to the *same* persistent storage (persistence manager, data store, and repository file system). However, each cluster node needs its own (private) repository directory, including repository.xml file, workspace FileSystem and Search index. It looks like you try to use the same repository directory.

I updated the [Jackrabbit cluster wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/Clustering) accordingly.

> Should I be using a DB persistence manager for both the PersistenceManager and Journal?

Yes, that's a good solution.

By the way, you could check how clustering is configured in the commercial [Day CRX](http://www.day.com/day/en/products/crx.html) (which is based on Jackrabbit). There is more [documentation about clustering](http://dev.day.com/content/docs/en/crx/current/administering/cluster.html), a lot of it applies to Jackrabbit as well. Disclaimer: I work for Day (now part of Adobe).

Comment: By the way, I updated the wiki page yesterday again. There is now a new example on how to use a clustered [H2 database](http://h2database.com) for Jackrabbit clustering.